# Averaging a Data Series in a Google Sheet to a single entry per period regardless of the number of samples in the larger period?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a small data set of ~200 samples taken over twenty years with two columns of data that sometimes have multiple entries for the period (i.e. age or date).  When I go to plot it, even though the data is over 20 years the graph heavily reflects the number of samples in the period and not the period itself. For example during age 23 there may be 2 or 3 samples, 1 for age 24, 20 for age 25, and 10 for age 35.. the number of samples entirely on needs for additional data at the time.. so simply there is no consistency to the sample rate.

How do I get an Max or an Average / Max for a period (age) and ensure there is only one entry per period in the sheet (about one entry per year) without having to create a separate sheet full of separate queries and charting off of that?

[image]

What I have tried in Google Sheets (where my data is) is on the x-series chart choosing "aggregate" (which is on the age period) which helps flatten the graph a bit, but doesn't reduce the series.

[image]

A read only link to the the [spreadsheet is HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WfjzNyoIhQRA9u_TUJEAiykVeXAbwkuZmuCsnsWQyqs/edit?usp=sharing) for reference.

Data Looking something like this:
3/27/2013   36.4247 2.5     29.3
4/10/2013   36.4630 1.8     42.8
4/15/2013   36.4767 2.2     33.9
5/2/2013    36.5233 2.2     33.9
5/21/2013   36.5753 1.91        39.9
5/29/2013   36.5973 1.94        39.2
7/29/2013   36.7644 1.98        38.3
10/25/2013  37.0055 1.7     45.6
2/28/2014   37.3507 1.85    50  41.3
6/1/2014    37.6055 1.98    38  38.1
12/1/2014   38.1068     37
6/1/2015    38.6055 2.18    34  33.9
12/11/2015  39.1342 3.03    23  23.1
12/14/2015  39.1425 3.18    22  21.9
12/15/2015  39.1452 3.44    20  20.0
12/17/2015  39.1507 3.61    19  18.9
12/21/2015  39.1616 3.62    19  18.8
12/23/2015  39.1671 3.32    21  20.8
12/25/2015  39.1726 3.08    23  22.7
12/28/2015  39.1808 3.12    22  22.4
12/29/2015  39.1836 2.97    24  23.7
12/30/2015  39.1863 3.57    19  19.1
12/31/2015  39.1890 3.37    20  20.5
1/1/2016    39.1918 3.37    20  20.5
1/3/2016    39.1973 2.65    27  27.0
1/4/2016    39.2000 2.76    26  25.8

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 Done; added link and pasted small set of sample data.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT({YEAR($A$6:$A), B6:B}, 1, 0, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 "where Col1 <> 1899")
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hNA_-GcFGPXyMvGO00LpKy6LtDH74K8yCsWdjjwikys/edit#gid=361050261)

and build a chart from there

Comment: If I wanted to break this out by Quarter or Month and have it be averages vs. Max (which this appears to be doing).. what modifications would I make to the query?

Comment: @CRSouser I added sheet for month